# Form page is not waiting for response from javascript sweetAlert?

Tags: javascript, php, sweetalert

Registration.php

```
<head>
<script>
    function myFunction() {
        var userName=document.getElementById('fname').value;
        var userLastName=document.getElementById('lname').value;
        var userEmail=document.getElementById('email').value;
        var userContact=document.getElementById('contact').value;
       //alert(userContact);
       var phoneno = /^\d{10}$/;
        var letters=/^[A-Za-z]+$/;

       if (letters.test(userName)) {

       }else{
       // swal("First Name contain only letters and whitespaces");
       swal({
        title: "Error!",
        text: "First Name contain only letters and whitespaces",
        type: "error",
        confirmButtonText: "OK"
        })
        exit;
       }

       if (letters.test(userLastName)) {

       }else{
        //alert("Last name contains only letters and whitespaces");
        swal({
            title:"Error!",
            text:"Last name contains only letters and whitespaces",
            type:"error",
            confirmButtonText:"OK"

            })
        exit;
       }
           if (phoneno.test(userContact)) {

       }else{
        //alert(" contact number is of 10 digit");
        swal({
            title:"Error!",
            text:"contact number is of 10 digit",
            type:"error",
            confirmButtonText: "OK"
            })
        exit;
       }
    ///alert("succes");
       //swal({
       // title:"Congratulation!",
       // text:"You are successfully Registreared.",
       // type:"success",
       // confirmButtonText: "OK",
       // })
      swal('Congratulations!','Your are successfully Register','success');

    }
</script>
</head>
    <body>
       <div id='Registration'>
    <form  action='Insert.php' method='post'>
    <table id='myTable'>
        <tr>
            <td id='tableName' colspan='2' style='text-align: center'>Registration</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>First Name: </td>
        <td><input  type='text' id='fname' name='fname' required></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Last Name:</td>
        <td><input type='text' id='lname' name='lname' required></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Email:</td>
        <td><input type='email' id='email' name='email' required></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Contact:</td>
        <td><input type='text' id='contact' name='contact' required></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td colspan='2' style='text-align: center'><input  type='submit' id='submit' value='SUBMIT' name='submit' onclick='myFunction()'></td>
    </tr>
</table>
</form>
</div>
 <body>
```

Here is my sweetAlert function which works fine for error but for success it doesn't work properly. For success it can't wait to get response from sweetAlert. Is their any problem in form action='insert.php' method='post'?
Please give me proper solution for it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is nothing with php.

This is normal flow of form submission. Once last line of `onclick` handler is executed, then browser starts sending the form to the server. Any native browser dialog like `alert` can pause this process, but none of the custom js alerts. If you want wait until user close an alert, then you should prevent form submission and submit it manually.

1. To prevent form submission(default behaviour) you should `return false` from your `onclick` handler - one of possible ways.
2. To submit form manually use `form.submit()` method
3. Use second argument of the `sval` function to add callback which will be executed after user close success dialog - http://t4t5.github.io/sweetalert/

So the result code may look like this: http://jsfiddle.net/7Ld8L6y5/

```
function myFunction() {
    var userName=document.getElementById('fname').value;
    var userLastName=document.getElementById('lname').value;
    var userEmail=document.getElementById('email').value;
    var userContact=document.getElementById('contact').value;

    var form = document.getElementById('myForm');
    var onDialogClose = function () {
        console.log(form);
        form.submit();
    };

    var phoneno = /^\d{10}$/;
    var letters=/^[A-Za-z]+$/;

    if (!letters.test(userName)) {
        swal({
            title: "Error!",
            text: "First Name contain only letters and whitespaces",
            type: "error",
            confirmButtonText: "OK"
        });
        return;
    }

    if (!letters.test(userLastName)) {
        swal({
            title:"Error!",
            text:"Last name contains only letters and whitespaces",
            type:"error",
            confirmButtonText:"OK"

        });
        return;
    }

    if (!phoneno.test(userContact)) {
        swal({
            title:"Error!",
            text:"contact number is of 10 digit",
            type:"error",
            confirmButtonText: "OK"
        })
        return;
    }

    swal({
        title: 'Congratulations',
        text: 'Your are successfully Register',
        type: 'success'
    }, onDialogClose);
}
```

You need to update your html code as well:

1. First you should update your `onclick` event handler for the `submit` button to prevent default behaviour - `onclick='myFunction(); return false;'`
2. Second you should rename your `submit` button to smth. like `send` to be able to call default `form.submit` method. Otherwise `form.submit` will reference to your button - `<input  type='submit' id='send' value='SUBMIT' name='send' onclick='myFunction(); return false;'>`

Also your original script contains an error: `javascript` does not have a built-in `exit` function. To skip an execution of the rest of a function code and immediately return a control - use the `return false;` statement.